# " I will wait for you but , if you will not come , i will leave the place

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

" I will wait for you but , if you will not come , i will leave the place  " is it correct using but and if at same place

Comment: Using _but_ and _if_ together is fine but, at least in BrE, your tenses seem wrong. I would write _if you do not come_.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect: if you will not come , I will leave the place.

Correct: If you **do not come**, I will leave the place.

First conditional- If + present + future

If you come, I will cook.

If it rains, I will not go out.

If I win the lottery, I will give him some money.

Comment: At the margins, *...if you **will** not come...* is syntactically valid in the cited context. It's just that it doesn't mean what OP probably wants to say (it means *...if you **refuse / are unwilling** to come...*).